# Installing casperJS 1.1.0 Dev on Windows 8

Tags: installation, casperjs, failed-installation

I am trying to install casperJS on Windows 8. First I install phantomjs 1.8.2

I go to [http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#casperjs-on-windows)
Download the zip under "Latest stable version". The site says its ver 1.0.3

I need 1.1.0 so I download the zip under "Latest development version (master branch):"
When I unzip it, add the path to PATH_VARIABLE and run it, I get error:
"CasperError: Can't find module cli"

Can someone plz tell from where can I get casperJS 1.1.0 for win8 ? I have spent entire day in this !

Comment: I don't have Win8, but the easiest installation is using npm: `npm -g install casperjs` but first you will need to install npm/node

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Visual Studio Node tools? (For some reason, with this package, attempting to install via the typical approach seemed to fail.) I was able to get installation to work by adding the casperjs line to my package.json file:

```
 "dependencies": {
"cheerio": "^0.19.0",
"express": "^4.13.3",
"request": "^2.61.0",
"casperjs": "^1.1.0-beta3"
```

}

When I saved the file, Visual Studio ran `npm install`, which successfully installed the package. Running the command manually after updating the package.json and CD'ing into the appropriate directory should achieve the same results.